# How to dynamically generate a regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have this regular expression `r'\b28\b'`. In this expression `28` should be dynamic. In other words, 28 is a dynamic value which the user enters. So, instead of 28 it can have 5. In that case, the expression would be `r'\b5\b'`.

I tried the below two approaches but they are not working.

1. r"r'\b" + room_number + r"\b'"
2. "r'\b" + room_number + "\b'"

I want to know how can I do it? Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the previous answer, you **should** generally use `r` for regular expression strings. But the way you had it, the `r` was inside the strings. It needs to go outside. It would look like this:

```
regex = r"\b" + str(my_var) + r"\b"
```

but in general it's nicer to use raw f-strings. This way you don't have to convert the `int` to a `str` yourself:

```
regex = rf"\b{my_var}\b"
```

Try running the following to see that it works:

```
import re

str_to_match = '3 45 72 3 45'
my_var = 45

regex = rf"\b{my_var}\b"

for f in re.findall(regex, str_to_match):
    print(f)
```

Outputs:

```
45
45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format string with [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), which will escape special characters for you:

```py
import re

room_number = 5
reg_expr = rf"\b{re.escape(str(room_number))}\b"
re.findall(reg_expr, "Room 5 is the target room.")
```

This outputs:

```py
['5']
```

Comment: that printed out `[]` on Python 3.10 for me.

Comment: @JLPeyret He/She should've used `rf""` instead of `f""` because of that `\b`.

Comment: hehe.  I also cribbed `rf"\b"` from them after my `"\b"` failed ;-)

Comment: Oops, fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are like me, I always pre-compile regexes.

(Not sure it always improves performance much, but I just find it a drag to remember both the compiled and the non-compiled syntax, so I picked using only the compiled.)

That solves your problem with f-strings:

```
import re

data = """
Look for 28
Look for 42
"""

target = 28
patre = re.compile(rf"\b{target}\b")


for line in data.splitlines():
    if patre.search(line):
        print(line)
```

##### output:

```
Look for 28
```

Comment: Even if there is no `re.compile`, the `re` module will automatically compile for us. It encapsulates `_compile()` function.

Comment: Yes, hence my remark about the perf gains not necessarily being not that helpful.  I think I started using re on Python versions before that got cached.  On closer look, my answer is similar to ldyer's which I upvoted.  Mostly because I only saw the `str(number)` initially in that answer, before writing this.